# Mechanize cannot find the form in login page

Tags: ruby, forms, mechanize

I am trying to use Ruby and Mechanize to log into a website, but with one particular log-in form I am having trouble. For some reason, Mechanize does not seem to recognize the form.

`Mechanize.new.get("website").form` returns nil and `forms` returns `[]`.

```
agent = Mechanize.new
fm_raw_mechanize = agent.get("https://www.fitmob.com/login")
fm_form = fm_raw_mechanize.form   #nil
fm_form.login = "rebeccamhathaway@gmail.com"
fm.password = "classpass"
fm.submit
```

Any ideas here?

Should I try another similar gem (recommendations)?

This is the source code from the "form". Notice the JavaScript `on_click`:

```
<div>
<div class="email_reg" id="email_reg"> 
<div id="email_box" class="form-group ">

<label for="email"></label>

<input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="kevin@gmail.com" placeholder="Email address">
</div>
<div id="pwd_box" class="form-group error">
<label for="pwd"></label>
<input type="password" name="pwd" id="pwd" placeholder="Password">
<span id="pwd_info" class="err">Valid passwords have 6 characters or more</span>

</div>

<a href="#" onclick="javascript:loggingTrack('web: pw reset click from login', {}, function(resp) {document.location = '/password/reset';});" class="forgot_pw">Forgot your password?</a>
</div>
<button id="login_email">Log in via email</button>

<span class="divider">or</span>
<div id="login_fb_box">
<button id="login_fb">Facebook Connect</button>
</div>

<span class="alternative">Don't have an account? <a href="/signup">Request an invite</a></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Looking at the doc.source, I don't see a <form> tag on that login page.  If you're looking for an alternatives to mechanize, there are a number of webdriver-based solutions (e.g. selenium, watir, gebish, etc.).

Comment: You can use Mechanize#post if you can't find a form to submit.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like the following:

```
$ pry
require 'mechanize'
agent = Mechanize.new
fm_raw_mechanize = agent.get('https://www.fitmob.com/login')
email_field = fm_raw_mechanize.at "#email"
email_field.attributes["value"].value = "me@email.com"
fm_raw_mechanize.at('input[@name="pwd"]')['value'] = "password"
agent.click(fm_raw_mechanize.at("#login_email"))
```

Comment: That wouldn't work, Mechanize doesn't have a javascript engine, it doesn't understand things like clicking buttons.